# Scatter data not overlaying properly on radar data... cartopy issue

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I'm trying to plot scatter data of storm reports on top of radar gridded data and I seem to be getting strange plotting issues related to mapping using cartopy. See [example image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iewEe.jpg). It appears that the scatter data plots on a separate axis than the radar data, but I'm not sure why given that the plotting module for the radar data uses the same user input for min/max lat/lon and the chosen projection. Additionally, the lat/lon range on the map is dynamic as I loop through time stamps. I know I can use an ax.set_extent to create fixed coordinates, but this does not solve my issue of the plotting being done on a separate axis.   Does anyone have any suggestions? They should overlay on the same axis.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import pyart
import pandas as pd

import nexradaws
import tempfile
import pytz

templocation = tempfile.mkdtemp()

import cartopy.feature as cfeature
from metpy.plots import USCOUNTIES


### Define the radar, start time and end time
radar_id = 'KDVN'
start = pd.Timestamp(2020,8,10,16,30).tz_localize(tz='UTC')
end = pd.Timestamp(2020,8,10,21,0).tz_localize(tz='UTC')

### Bounds of map we want to plot
min_lon = -93.25
max_lon = -88.
min_lat = 40.35
max_lat = 43.35

# ### Bounds of map we want to plot
# min_lon = -80.8
# max_lon = -77.
# min_lat = 34
# max_lat = 37


#### and get the data
conn = nexradaws.NexradAwsInterface()
scans = conn.get_avail_scans_in_range(start, end, radar_id)
print("There are {} scans available between {} and {}\n".format(len(scans), start, end))
print(scans[0:4])

## download these files
#results = conn.download(scans[0:2], templocation)
results = conn.download(scans, templocation)

#%%

#Now get the severe reports from the SPC site. This assumes you're plotting a year far #enough in the past that 
 #  SPC has official records available. If plotting a more recent time period, then the #local storm reports archive 
 #[![enter image description here][1]][1]  at IEM is a good source
   
   
### wind reports
wind_rpts = pd.read_csv("https://www.spc.noaa.gov/wcm/data/"+str(start.year)+"_wind.csv")

wind_rpts['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(wind_rpts.date + ' ' + wind_rpts.time) ## convert to datetime
wind_rpts.set_index("datetime",inplace=True)

### times in the file are given in central standard time (UTC+6). Localize, and convert to UTC
wind_rpts.index = wind_rpts.index.tz_localize("Etc/GMT+6",ambiguous='NaT',nonexistent='shift_forward').tz_convert("UTC")

## subset down to 30 minutes before/after the radar times we're plotting
wind_rpts = wind_rpts[((start-pd.Timedelta(minutes=30)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")):((end+pd.Timedelta(minutes=30)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))]
wind_rpts


### repeat for tornado reports
tor_rpts = pd.read_csv("https://www.spc.noaa.gov/wcm/data/"+str(start.year)+"_torn.csv")

tor_rpts['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(tor_rpts.date + ' ' + tor_rpts.time) ## convert to datetime
tor_rpts.set_index("datetime",inplace=True)

### times in the file are given in central standard time (UTC+6). Localize, and convert to UTC
tor_rpts.index = tor_rpts.index.tz_localize("Etc/GMT+6",ambiguous='NaT',nonexistent='shift_forward').tz_convert("UTC")

## subset down to 30 minutes before/after the radar times we're plotting
tor_rpts = tor_rpts[((start-pd.Timedelta(minutes=30)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")):((end+pd.Timedelta(minutes=30)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))]
tor_rpts
### repeat for hail
hail_rpts = pd.read_csv("https://www.spc.noaa.gov/wcm/data/"+str(start.year)+"_hail.csv")

hail_rpts['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(hail_rpts.date + ' ' + hail_rpts.time) ## convert to datetime
hail_rpts.set_index("datetime",inplace=True)

### times in the file are given in central standard time (UTC+6). Localize, and convert to UTC
hail_rpts.index = hail_rpts.index.tz_localize("Etc/GMT+6",ambiguous='NaT',nonexistent='shift_forward').tz_convert("UTC")

## subset down to 30 minutes before/after the radar times we're plotting
hail_rpts = hail_rpts[((start-pd.Timedelta(minutes=30)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")):((end+pd.Timedelta(minutes=30)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))]
hail_rpts


#%%

'''Now we plot the maps and animate'''

### loop over the radar images that have been downloaded

for i,scan in enumerate(results.iter_success(),start=1):
#for i in range(0,1):
    ## skip the files ending in "MDM"
    if scan.filename[-3:] != "MDM":
        
        print(str(i))
        print("working on "+scan.filename)
        
        this_time = pd.to_datetime(scan.filename[4:17], format="%Y%m%d_%H%M").tz_localize("UTC")
    
        radar = scan.open_pyart()
        #display = pyart.graph.RadarDisplay(radar)

        fig = plt.figure(figsize=[15, 7])

        map_panel_axes = [0.05, 0.05, .4, .80]
        x_cut_panel_axes = [0.55, 0.10, .4, .25]
        y_cut_panel_axes = [0.55, 0.50, .4, .25]

        projection = ccrs.PlateCarree()

        ## apply gatefilter (see here: https://arm-doe.github.io/pyart/notebooks/masking_data_with_gatefilters.html)
        #gatefilter = pyart.correct.moment_based_gate_filter(radar)
        gatefilter = pyart.filters.GateFilter(radar)

        # Lets remove reflectivity values below a threshold.
        gatefilter.exclude_below('reflectivity', -2.5)

        display = pyart.graph.RadarMapDisplay(radar)
       
        ### set up plot
        ax1 = fig.add_axes(map_panel_axes, projection=projection)
        
        # Add some various map elements to the plot to make it recognizable.
        ax1.add_feature(USCOUNTIES.with_scale('500k'), edgecolor="gray", linewidth=0.4)
        #ax1.coastlines('50m', edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.75)
        ax1.add_feature(cfeature.STATES.with_scale('10m'), linewidth=1.0)
    
        cf = display.plot_ppi_map('reflectivity', 0, vmin=-7.5, vmax=65,
                          min_lon=min_lon, max_lon=max_lon, min_lat=min_lat, max_lat=max_lat,
                          title=radar_id+" reflectivity and severe weather reports, "+this_time.strftime("%H%M UTC %d %b %Y"),
                          projection=projection, resolution='10m',
                             gatefilter=gatefilter,
                          cmap='pyart_HomeyerRainbow', 
                          colorbar_flag=False,
                          lat_lines=[0,0], lon_lines=[0,0]) ## turns off lat/lon grid lines
        #display.plot_crosshairs(lon=lon, lat=lat)
        
        ## plot horizontal colorbar 
        display.plot_colorbar(cf,orient='horizontal', pad=0.07)
        
        # Plot range rings if desired
        #display.plot_range_ring(25., color='gray', linestyle='dashed')
        #display.plot_range_ring(50., color='gray', linestyle='dashed')
        #display.plot_range_ring(100., color='gray', linestyle='dashed')

        ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(min_lon, max_lon, .5), crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
        ax1.set_yticks(np.arange(min_lat, max_lat, .5), crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())     
       
        ## add marker points for severe reports
        wind_rpts_now = wind_rpts[((start-pd.Timedelta(minutes=30)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")):this_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")]
        ax1.scatter(wind_rpts_now.slon.values.tolist(), wind_rpts_now.slat.values.tolist(), s=20, facecolors='none', edgecolors='mediumblue', linewidths=1.8)
        tor_rpts_now = tor_rpts[((start-pd.Timedelta(minutes=30)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")):this_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")]
        ax1.scatter(tor_rpts_now.slon.values.tolist(), tor_rpts_now.slat.values.tolist(), s=20, facecolors='red', edgecolors='black', marker="v",linewidths=1.5)
        hail_rpts_now = hail_rpts[((start-pd.Timedelta(minutes=30)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")):this_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")]
        ax1.scatter(hail_rpts_now.slon.values.tolist(), hail_rpts_now.slat.values.tolist(), s=20, facecolors='none', edgecolors='green', linewidths=1.8)

        
        plt.savefig(scan.radar_id+"_"+scan.filename[4:17]+"_dz_rpts.png",bbox_inches='tight',dpi=300,
                   facecolor='white', transparent=False)
        #plt.show()
        plt.close('all')
```

Comment: Please see the guide to [formatting](/help/formatting) and creating a [mre]

Comment: You should probably add something like `ax=ax1` to the call of `plot_ppi_map()`. But it's impossible to test without a working example.